# Change VisualState of ListBox element

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I've got a Lisbox in which I've made a ItemsTemplate, in this itemTemplate I've got a element in which I wish to change the visualState, The problem is I do not know how to change the state. Here is what I've got so far.

```
<ListBox Name="My_LB" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  Canvas.Left="45.8256" Canvas.Top="39.3065" Canvas.ZIndex="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                            
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="user_ellipse" Width="7.87566" Height="7.87563" Canvas.Left="25.3505" Canvas.Top="5.08428e-005" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.6" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000">
                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IsTurn">
                                                <VisualState x:Name="PlayersTurn">
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetName="user_ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetName="user_ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"/>
                                                        <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Storyboard.TargetName="user_ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)"/>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </VisualState>
                                            </VisualStateGroup> 
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.651141" RadiusY="0.651175" Center="0.380114,0.308228" GradientOrigin="0.380114,0.308228">
                                            <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <RotateTransform CenterX="0.380114" CenterY="0.308228" Angle="47.4886"/>
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9065" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF4F4832" Offset="0.685767"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="1"/>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

This is what I've got so far, if anyone could just help me change the state in anyway to start of with, that would be appreciated.

Further if possible I would like to change the state depending on a parameter in my ViewModel, I'm using the MVVM design, I've found this [soltuion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190058/how-to-change-visualstate-via-viewmodel/12816035#comment37095963_12816035), but I do not know the namespace of "b", and d hence do not know how to get the "VisualStateSettingBehavior".

**UPDATE**
I've changed my Ellipse to a button and made a style for the button in my resourcedictionary, so what I have now is:

The MainPage:

```
 <ListBox Name="My_LB" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"  Canvas.Left="45.8256" Canvas.Top="39.3065" Canvas.ZIndex="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">                            
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
<Button Name="Shield_Light" Canvas.Left="25.3505" Canvas.Top="5.08428e-005" Style="{StaticResource Style1}"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And in my ResourceDictionary I've got the syle:

```
<Style x:Key="Style" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse_Light" Width="7.87566" Height="7.87563" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.6" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="Red">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommomStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="IsNotTurn"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="IsTurn">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse_Light" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" To="Yellow"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Ellipse>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>


</Style>
```

But i still do not know how to change the VisualState such that it turn yellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start of it is a good idea to make your ellipse to a button instead, as you've done in the updated version. However your targetProperty for the storyboard is not set correct, you should ser it to:

```
Storyboard.Targetproperty ="(Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

If you wish to change the VisualState from the code behind you should find the Button and then change the state of it. I found these two examples which helped me:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016614/wp7-silverlight-how-to-animate-a-listboxitem-on-selectionchanged)

[2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/86718319-b994-4516-8e8c-ef758c769c68/how-can-i-change-the-visual-state-of-a-listbox-item-based-on-a-property?forum=wpdevelop)

That is you find the button through the visualTreeHelper and obj.FindName.

If you however want to change the VisualState from the ViewModel you should make an **Attached property**, these two sites will help you with this:

[3](http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/using-the-visualstatemanager-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-pattern-in-wpf-or-silverlight/)

[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002046/binding-visualstatemanager-view-state-to-a-mvvm-viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below menioned code

```
 VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PlayersTurn", false);
```

Comment: I tried applying it in the code behind, but it doesn't do anything. Are you sure i'm actually applying to the itemtemplate?

Comment: So you recommend I make a style in my resources where I put it?

Comment: you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053112/wpf-button-mouse-moveover-change-color/24053354#24053354

Comment: I tried doing similar things to my Ellipse as you did for the Button, but I can't (Don't know how) use the VisualStaeManager in the <setter Property=Fill>.